# OnNotification() function dosen't work when i send localNotification

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I am using react-native-push-notification to implement push notifications, I have followed the documentation properly when I send remote notification OnNotification() get called properly but when I send LocalNotification using PushNotification.LocalNotification() I get proper notification pop-up but it doesn't trigger OnNotification() function, I have gone through lot of stackoverflow questions and git issue still no solution, can anyone have solution have on this issue that would be great help

Answer (score 0):

For ios this method will trigger/callback when you click on the notification and launch the app from killed state

```
 PushNotificationIOS.getInitialNotification().then(notification => {
     if (!notification) {
      return;
   }
 });
```

I just implemented and tested in release mode, it worked well. For Andriod i'm still figuring it out which method triggers the call back in killed state.

Note: Above code works only in release mode for iOS.